# Sending input to netcat during connection in Python

Tags: linux, python-3.x, system-calls, netcat

I want to connect to 2018shell.picoctf.com by netcat using python. I need to read output(which I accomplished) and later write "210.205.230.140" and send it to the server.

```
import subprocess


proces = subprocess.Popen(["nc", "2018shell.picoctf.com", "14079"], 
                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                          stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

data = proces.communicate(input=b'210.205.230.140')
```

I don't know why program gets stuck in `proces.communicate(input=b'210.205.230.140')` and I can't send it to subproces and get next messages sent by server or execute next commands.

Comment: `nc` usually means `netcat`, not `netcut`. Do you have special software? If not please correct the spelling your Q. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, no I don't have any special software